# HTML/CSS Add space in new line of filter params

Tags: html, css

I'm using Bootstrap in my app where I've got a multiple filters above my table. How to add some space between `Date Min` line and `Payment Method` line? Here is screenshot which better describes my issue:

[image]

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/71tr3sqj/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col text-end">
    <form data-controller="transactions-form" data-transactions-form-target="form" data-turbo-frame="transactions" action="/transactions" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get">
      <label for="platform_payment_id">Order Id</label>
      <input data-action="input->transactions-form#search" type="text" name="platform_payment_id" id="platform_payment_id">
      <label for="min_amount">Min Amount</label>
      <input data-action="input->transactions-form#search" type="text" name="min_amount" id="min_amount">
      <label for="max_amount">Max Amount</label>
      <input data-action="input->transactions-form#search" type="text" name="max_amount" id="max_amount">
      <label for="payer_name">Payer Name</label>
      <input data-action="input->transactions-form#search" type="text" name="payer_name" id="payer_name">
      <label for="date_min">
        <span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.transactions.table.date_min">Date Min</span>
      </label>
      <input data-action="input->transactions-form#search" type="date" name="date_min" id="date_min">
      <label for="date_max">
        <span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.transactions.table.date_max">Date Max</span>
      </label>
      <input data-action="input->transactions-form#search" type="date" name="date_max" id="date_max">
      <label for="payment_method">Payment Method</label>
      <select data-action="change->transactions-form#search" name="payment_method" id="payment_method">
        <option value="">All Methods</option>
        <option value="directdebit">Direct Debit</option>
        <option value="creditcard">Credit Card</option>
      </select>
      <label for="status">Status</label>
      <select data-action="change->transactions-form#search" name="status" id="status">
        <option value="">All Statuses</option>
        <option value="awaiting_authentication">Awaiting Authentication</option>
        <option value="awaiting_clearance">Awaiting Clearance</option>
        <option value="awaiting_user_input">Awaiting User Input</option>
        <option value="fully_paid">Fully Paid</option>
        <option value="payment_declined">Payment Declined</option>
        <option value="user_canceled">User Canceled</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Circumventing any framework you can add CSS like `form { line-height: 2 }` and/or change the inline `line-height` to any value you require...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap each elements with div and add `mb-2`

```html
<form method="get">
    <div class="mb-2">
        <label for="">Order Id</label>
        <input type="text" name="">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try use flex & gap, check this
https://jsfiddle.net/nw4qhbtk/

```
<form data-controller="transactions-form" data-transactions-form-target="form" data-turbo-frame="transactions" action="/transactions" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;gap: 10px;">
  <div>
    <label for="platform_payment_id">Order Id</label>
    <input data-action="input->transactions-form#search" type="text" name="platform_payment_id" id="platform_payment_id">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="min_amount">Min Amount</label>
    <input data-action="input->transactions-form#search" type="text" name="min_amount" id="min_amount">
  </div>
</form>
```